# cocoa - get iphone address group

Tags: ios, ios5, contacts, addressbook

Is there any way to get the group of a contact in the address book?

I can get all the info about a contact, but I can't find out how to get the group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if u might get group of a contact but u can know a contact is of group type or not by this or [refer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AddressBook/Reference/ABRecordRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/ABRecordGetRecordType) link:

```
 ABRecordGetRecordType : Returns the type of a record.

 ABRecordType ABRecordGetRecordType (
 ABRecordRef record
 );

Parameters : record
The record whose type is being returned.

Return Value : The record type of record:

kABPersonType for person records
kABGroupType for group records.
kABSourceType for source records.
```